# I'm not able to add data into the dropdown

Tags: angular, angularfire

I have data called categories. I'm able to fetching the data from firebase however I'm having some problems while adding the data to dropdown. I can see the data on the console. I get the data through Firebase.

.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-6">
        <h5>Choose Category</h5>
        <select class="form-select" >
          <option *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category?.name}} 
          </option>
        </select>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

.ts

```
export class ProfileUpdateTwoComponent implements OnInit {

  categories: Category[] = []

  constructor(public realtime: RealtimeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listCategory()
    console.log(this.categories)
  }

   listCategory(){
      this.realtime.listCategory().snapshotChanges().subscribe(data=>{
      data.forEach(k=>{
        const x = { ...k.payload.toJSON(), key:k.key}
        this.categories.push(x as Category)
      })
    })
  }

}
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Bqu.png)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSoDP.png)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code sandbox?

Comment: [sandbox1](https://hizliresim.com/6i31oi) [code1](https://hizliresim.com/s9e3ua)  [code2](https://hizliresim.com/6m6vpo)  [console](https://hizliresim.com/1byt33)

Comment: Screenshot wont help to debug. Can you create add you code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuo2ye?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Is that enough? I couldn't add the firebase link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lbq2hg?file=src/app/components/profile-update/profile-update.component.ts

Comment: Can u save the firebase response data as well do the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add in the async pipe to your ngFor statement. Are you receiving any errors in your console?

```
<option *ngFor="let category of categories | async">{{category?.name}} 
</option>
```

I would also recommend importing Observable from rxjs

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

and then update your categories object to the following

```
categories: Observable<Category[]>;
```

then add the async pipe to your *ngFor loop.

Comment: No. Everything is fine on Console. I created a component similar to this. It works. However, it does not work on the new component. [link](https://resmim.net/aqn2qw/) [link](https://resmim.net/aqn2qw/)

Comment: I would recommend hooking up [Angular Fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).
They have much better functions for calling out to firebase, and firebase will watch for valuechanges as well.